# Java replaceAll with []* - all characters are found (length of 9) but result length is two

Tags: java, regex

I've just started learning about regex and have the following code:

```
 [1] String replace2 = "chocolate".replaceAll("[a-z]*","*");
 [2] System.out.println(replace2);                   //output: **
 [3] replace2 = "chocolate".replaceAll("[a-c]*","*");
 [4] System.out.println(replace2);                  //output: **h*o**o*l**t*e*
```

I don't understand how * works in this situation:

Referring to [3], my understanding is that each found character is replaced with a single star and each unfound character is replaced with "a single star + the unfound character"

For example, the first char in the string "chocolate" is c so replace it with *. Second char is h and it's not what we want so retain it with *h. I can match this logic with the output at [4].

My question is why is [2] returning two stars?

Comment: try this `String replace2 = "chocolate".replaceAll("[a-z]","*");` !

Comment: In [1] your regex matches the whole string (any number of letters) and you therefore get one star only.

Comment: @Maraboc it works fine with your code, thank you. But I'm trying to understand why the output is such when I use "[a-z]*" Could you share with me about this please?

Comment: @assylias I'm getting two stars thus my question about it.

Comment: Because *  The asterisk indicates zero or more occurrences of the preceding element. For example, ab*c matches "ac", "abc", "abbc", "abbbc", and so on. :)

Comment: And in your case `[a-z]*` will match zero or mores characters !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The asterisk `*`mark means in RegEx, that "zero or more" occurrence of the previous pattern is matched.

In your case line `[1]` matches the whole string, and then matches an empty string, hence the `**` result.

In line `[3]` each matching letter or letters would be matched, but after each of them an empty string is matched. See: https://regex101.com/r/sTmd9k/1

Comment: Thank you for correcting my understanding of line [3].

Answer (score 0):

To get 1 star use `+`

```
String replace2 = "chocolate".replaceAll("[a-z]+","*");
```

using `*` will find also empty string